# Are there some existing impressive ExtJS examples online?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I'm trying to convince my boss to use EXTJS for our client side scripting, are there any eye poppers out there? I've already found some [old](http://www.sencha.com/learn/legacy/Manual%3aSightings) examples but none are very impressive. The closest to impressive is that I've found is [cubedrive](http://www.cubedrive.com/). These are the kinds of examples I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is also a nice one 
[SCircles](http://circles.source-lounge.de/web/SCircles/Circles/). More info about it [on sencha forums](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?152143-S-CIRCLES-Social-Network-Engine-%28Ext-JS-4-ST-1.1%29).
Also : 
[ClickTime](http://clicktime.com/)

*edit*

I found more:

- [CodeSmith Tools](http://www.sencha.com/blog/ext-js-spotlight-codesmith-tools)
- [Kohive](http://www.sencha.com/blog/implementation-spotlight-kohive)
- [Attensa](http://www.sencha.com/blog/implementation-spotlight-attensa)
- [Xero](http://www.sencha.com/blog/implementation-spotlight-xero)
- [Zipwhip](http://www.sencha.com/blog/implementation-spotlight-zipwhip-and-ext-js)
- [Marketo](http://www.sencha.com/blog/implementation-spotlight-marketo)
- [Jama Contour](http://www.sencha.com/blog/implementation-spotlight-jama-contour)
- [VersoChat](http://www.sencha.com/blog/implementation-spotlight-versochat)
- [SingleHop Leap](http://www.sencha.com/blog/implementation-spotlight-singlehop-leap)

Comment: Thank you. These are the types of links I'm looking for. I'd vote your response up if I had enough reputation :).